# redirect iphone app to apple store

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, itunes-store

I have an iphone app, and when there are upgrades available, I want to prompt the user to upgrade, and if they click upgrade, I want to redirect them to the apple store. How is this done?

Thanks

Comment: Also note that you may need to wait a while (up to 24 hours?) for caches to refresh. Back in the day, App Store would say that updates were available but clicking "update" would just reinstall the old version (presumably since it was cached on the server); occasionally there's also the user that sees a "update posted!" tweet/etc but can't see it on the App Store.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple documents the process here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html

The basics boils down to using an NSURL to open an iTunes link:

```
NSString *iTunesLink = @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/warehouse51/id364201184?mt=8";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:iTunesLink]];
```

However, I don't believe there is a way to direct to the upgrade tab.

Note: phobos links are generally outdated, so ignore that your link won't look like the example in Apple's doc.  It will generally look like the one in my updated example here.

Comment: Annoyingly, 4.2 GM shows "Free/Install" or "$1.99/Buy Now" even if you have a previous version installed (oh well). Not sure if they've fixed this in 4.2.1; I doubt it somehow!

Answer (score 0):

Just open the appropriate iTunes URL for your application. Users will have to go to the update tab on their own, though.

Answer (score -1):

You'll either want to use a Push notification, or have your app check somewhere online (that you can update) so when an update is available you can present an alert. Then, upon an OK from the user, simply send 'em to your app in the store using the itunes URL.

Comment: -1 Push notifications are not allowed to be used for "marketing", which includes prompting users to upgrade.